# Which calculation is easier for a computer?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computer-science, computer-arithmetic

I have two problems and I want to know which one is easier to handle for a computer (running time, number of needed operations....):

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$ and vector $d \in \mathbb{Z}^m$

1. Find a vector y such that $y^TA=0, y\geq 0, y^Td>0$
2. Find a vector y such that $y^TA \in \mathbb{Z}^n, y^Td \notin \mathbb{Z}$

The expressions as $y \geq 0$ have to be understood componentwise. If it helps, the first one is called Farkas Lemma and the second one lattice analouge Farkas Lemma.

Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: Have you got any idea about the problem? Have you tried anything? With these informations, it would be much easier to answer the question to your satisfaction.

Comment: For humans obviously problem 1 is easier to solve. For the second one you have to analyse the simple expressions and hope to be able to find some more information. But a computer can not do this analysis. I do not know how a computer would even be able to solve problem 2.